# NLog with azure blob storage container file size

Tags: nlog, azure-blob-storage

I have configure NLog with azure BLOB storage in my application. But if my log 
content is too big like 500 000 lines, then it just stores only 50 000.

How many log line i can store per BLOB container file?

Answer (score 2):

Think you are meeting the hard limit of 50000 blocks in a single blob:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets#azure-blob-storage-scale-targets

When writing single line at a time, then each line becomes a single block.

I guess the NLog Blob Target should have some batch-logic, and only write every 1-2 sec. (Can be done by applying AsyncWrapper or BufferingWrapper with non-frequent flush interval).

I guess the NLog Blob Target should try and keep track of the number of write-operations. And automatically roll when having reached 49999 writes (And also roll when failing because of reached block limit).

Answer (score 1):

New updated NLog Blob Storage Target has been created. It performs batching by default, and reduces the chance of meeting the 50000 file-operations limit.

See: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/